# Why submit didn't work in my jquery script?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I find out the reason. It's my miss to add code on an old. I didn't notice an existing form is there from the very beginning and mistakenly add anther form in it. I keep the original content.

My html and script is like below. It's using Django and it's a Django template but I think this is a issue not related to Django. It displays a list of dir or files(if any) which are arranged in ul and li elements. When I click on any list item(li element), I expect it will trigger a submit. **I can saw the alert() window, but I didn't see the post request from the server side.** I have a similar snippet in another place of my project and that works, but this don't. I can't think out what I had missed?

```
<form id="id_f_sel" action="{% url 'integratedTest:addCase' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" id="id_f_clked" name="f_clked" value="">
            <ul id="id_dirlist">
                {%for item in dirs %}
                    <li><img src="{% static 'image/folder.png' %}" alt="unclicked folder image">
                    <span class="caret">{{item}}</span></li>
                {%endfor%}
            </ul>
        
            <ul id="id_flist">
                {%for item in files %}
                    <li><img src="{% static 'image/file.png' %}" alt="file image">
                    <span class="caret">{{item}}</span></li>
                {%endfor%}
            </ul>            
        </form>

<script>  
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $('li').on('click', function() { 
          clk_val = $(this).text()  
          alert(clk_val)
          $('#id_f_clked').val(clk_val)  
          $('#id_f_sel').submit()          
        });
    });
</script>
```

The browser dev windows networks tab is very clean. It seems no request is sent out. Some lines "[Violation] 'click' handler took 1272ms" I can't understand.
[image: browser networks windows]

Comment: check the browser *developer* tools console for errors ... also, check the network tab of same to see if the browser is making the request in the first place

Comment: I didn't see any request. It's very clean and a message "[Violation] 'click' handler took 1272ms". I don't know the meaning.

Comment: probably the `alert` causing that - change it to a `console.log` instead since alerts block the main thread - this is why `alert` should never be used for debugging, especially in an event handler

Comment: I tried delete the alert line and changed to another browser(originally Chrome and later Edge). The problem still there.

Comment: no errors? no actual request being sent?

Comment: Yes. No error/warning and no request caught from the dev tools.

Comment: I see you are NOT logging `XMLHttpRequests`  - so how do you know your browser isn't making them? nevermind ... this isn't an XMLHttpRequest - I got confused :p but, since this is a form post, perhaps you should enable "preserve log" - since a new page will be loaded on the submit action

Comment: by the way, if you think you're being diverse by using Chrome and then Edge to test your code ... that's like test driving a blue and red car of the exact same model and thinking they'll perform differently - Edge is just the Chrome pig with Microsofts lipstick applied

Comment: I checked but nothing. After I delete alert line the violation line disappeared. I found in issue message: Page layout may be unexpected due to Quirks Mode. Not sure it matters or not.

Comment: OK. For Chrome and Edge. I didn't know they use the same engine. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Quirks mode just means the resulting HTML is from the 1990's :p

Comment: I find out the reason. The form I newly added is in another form I didn't noticed.   I didn't paste the whole code because I didn't see and realise that. Just found.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to use a `<input type="submit">` instead of using a li with a click function. Or try to prevent your form from being submitted and then trigger the function.

Follow the documentation!

https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: There're many li items here. Every li click will request different things and update immediately. Button need click and submit with one more click on different elements, need mouse move. Lost easy operation for my project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).